# Merge two graphs in neo4j with same node name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I built two graphs in neo4j :
the first one has two nodes - **topic and news**, which has relationship - topic,
and the second graph that has two nodes also - **news and user**, and has relationship - been clicked.
My question is : **can I combine these two graphs by news node**?

My graph looks like the picture below, and I want it to combine together.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the APOC extended procedure [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/) to combine nodes, and optionally their relationships.

For example, this query combines `News` nodes that have the same `id`. The config options specify that the resulting combined node keeps only a single copy of the `id` property value, and stores a list of combined values for the other properties. It also specifies that the relationships of the original nodes are retained by the resulting node.

```
MATCH (n:News)
WITH n.id AS id, COLLECT(n) AS list
WHERE SIZE(list) > 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(list, {
  id: 'discard',
  properties: 'combine',
  mergeRels: true
}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```